# When allocating dynamic array in C, is there a general rule to how much memory to allocate when the amount of memory that will be utilized is unknown?

Tags: c

When allocating a dynamic array in C, is there any general rule on how much memory to allocate when the amount of memory that will be utilized is unknown?

For example, when dynamic memory allocation is for a string command line argument with no character limitation.

Comment: Allocate more if you need, and deallocate if you think there's no more need.

Comment: For this case the limitation would be maximum cmdline length that the shell can support. I might be wrong here, but on *Win* I think it's 32k chars.

Comment: Allocate as large as you can. Otherwise, some input string is going to break your code even before you can `strlen()` it. If you know in advance that your memory is not enough, use `realloc()`

Comment: There is a general practice to allocate the amount you reasonably anticipate using, and then to `realloc` by a factor of 2 (or whatever you want) as needed. Meaning, if you have a file of unknown length and you wish to allocate pointers (to which you will assign allocated lines), then initially allocate, say `16` pointers, which will be fine for short files, but will scale very well for large files as well (e.g. `16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, ...`). The goal is to reduce the number of allocations to a reasonable minimum, but don't lose sleep over whether that will be 12 or 31, etc..

Comment: There can be no "general rule" as the strategy employed would depend on resource availability and application specifics - that is it is not reasonable to expect typed user input of several Mb, but stream-data over a network may well be. What you might get is some useful guidelines for specific situations - not _rules_.

Answer (score 4):

The task of (re)allocating memory is often resource-expensive and shouldn't be done often. The general rule, as used by for example a lot of C++ library container classes:

- At start, allocate `n * [system alignment]` bytes.
- When the input no longer fits the allocated segment, re-allocate it with twice the previous size. Repeat each time you run out of memory.

That is, exponentially increase the amount of allocated memory.

Comment: I think, you should add that the point of the constant factor increment is, to get the complexity of the copy-over operations down to `O(N)` (instead of `O(N^2)` in the case of constant increment).